# Electron, I can't use BrowserWindow to explore file system

Tags: electron, local

I'm trying to show a folder of the machine running an Electron app, I already look and see I can load the url `file:///d:/` on my machine and see the folder content but noway to do that with a BrowserWindow. I can see in the DevTools an error saying

```
Not allowed to load local resource.
```

Is there a workaround or any setup to be able to do that?

I use the following code:

```
ipcMain.on('openExplorer', (event, arg) => {
  exploreWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 120, height: 82, title: "MyApp", icon: "assets/images/favicon.ico" });
  exploreWindow.setTitle('Files Explorer');
  addr = 'file:///d://' ;
  console.log(addr);
  exploreWindow.loadURL(addr);      
  exploreWindow.openDevTools();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons it is a good idea to not grant a BrowserWindow access to the filesystem. If you still want to do so you could use the **inter process communication** module to access the filesystem from your mainfile and send it to your BrowserWindow.

See:

[Electron Documentation for `ipcMain`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/)

[Electron Documentation for `ipcRenderer`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/)